How to transfer local scene from ArcGIS Pro to NVidia Omniverse
I am working on a project where we have created a local scene of the Jezero Crater on Mars using ArcGIS Pro. Our goal is to move this scene into NVidia Omniverse to apply physics simulations. The scene is composed only of elevation data and surface imagery raster datasets.
We have access to the following software:

ArcGIS Pro
CityEngine (free trial)
NVidia Omniverse

I have put the local scene into a geodatabase and tried to import it into CityEngine to then export it to a 3D format such as .usd, .obj, or .stl (since CityEngine can do this but ArcGIS Pro cannot). However, CityEngine cannot import rasters.
How do we export raster data from ArcGIS Pro into a compatible 3D format and ensure a smooth import into NVidia Omniverse?
